# Making a method so as to be able to move the ball in PapiJump sideways by touching the sides of the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, touch

I am new in the game, so this is probably a stupid question, but I am experiencing a great deal of trouble over this code I am working on. I am trying to make the ball go to the right when you press the right side of the screen, and vise versa for the left, but thus far it crashes when I touch the screen :-(

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

if (gameState == kStateRunning && controlType == kTouch) {
    if (location.x < (self.view.bounds.size.width/2)) {
        touchState = kLeftDown;
        ballVelocity.x -= 0.2;
    }
    else {
        touchState = kRightDown;
        ballVelocity.x += 0.2;
    }
}

if (gameState == kStateGameOver) {
    if (location.x < (self.view.bounds.size.width/2)) {
        gameState = kStateMenu;
    }
    else {
        gameState = kStateRunning;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing obviously wrong there that I can see (assuming you have defined all your constants, etc.)

Having been bitten by it a few times, the first thing I check now with odd crashes is if there are any broken IBOutlet or IBAction links on the viewController owner (indicated by those orange alert triangles).

I guess then I would comment out everything within that function and see if it still crashes. Then NSLog statements, etc - standard debugging.